# Open Safari from UITableView Section

Tags: ios, nsstring, mobile-safari

I have a TableView that has a section that is clickable.  Under that section I want the application to open Safari, with a specific google search that is determined by some data that I am feeding in.

I have verified that the string I am feeding in is valid and showing the correct URL, also I have tried this code whilst hard-coding the URL into the last line, and it opens just fine.  However as it is set now, when I click the button, nothing happens at all.

```
NSMutableString *searchString = [_venueInfo objectAtIndex:3];
NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalString]];
```

Comment: Have you tried to NSLog(@"%@", finalString), does it print what is expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to use NSString ,don't use NSMutableString.Let me know is it working or not man...!!